# Unable To Align Tooltip Next To Input/Label Field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have developed a tooltip using HTML and CSS. The tooltip is triggered upon hovering over an image. However, when i place my image next to a textbox/input, it is not inline with the input box, possibly because there is some absolute positioning.

```
<div class="box">
  <ul class="list">
     <li>
       <label for="email"><span class="mandatoryField">* </span>Email address</label>                       
       <input id="email" name="email" class="one-quarter" type="text" onblur="MakeLowerCase(this);"/>

         <a class="tooltip" href="#"><img src="images/information.png" alt="Information" height="25" width="25"/><span class="custom info"><img src="images/information.png" alt="Information" height="48" width="48"/><em>Information</em>This is just an example of what you can do using a CSS tooltip, feel free to get creative and produce your own!</span></a>

     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
a.tooltip {
border-bottom:1px dotted #000;
color:#000;
outline:none;
cursor:help;
text-decoration:none;
position:relative;
}

a.tooltip span { 
position:absolute;
top:2em;
left:1em;
width:250px;
margin-left:-99em;
opacity:0;
text-decoration:none!important;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
box-shadow:2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-transition-property:opacity;
-moz-transition-duration:1s;
-webkit-transition-property:opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration:1s;
-o-transition-property:opacity;
-o-transition-duration:1s;
}

a.tooltip:hover span {
font-family:Calibri,Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;
z-index:99;
margin-left:0;
opacity:1;
}

a.tooltip.top:hover span { 
  top:2em;  
  margin-left:auto;
}

a.tooltip img {
position:absolute;
border:0;margin:-10px 0 0 -55px;
float:left;
}

a.tooltip em { 
font:700 1.2em Candara,Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;
display:block;padding:0.2em 0 0.6em 0;
}

.custom {
padding:0.5em 0.8em 0.8em 2em;
}

* html a:hover { 
background:transparent;
}

.critical {
 background:#fca;
 border:1px solid #ff3334;
}

.help {
background:#9fdaee;
border:1px solid #2bb0d7;
}

.info {
background:#3f97b5;
border:1px solid #2bb0d7;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: share some fiddle for the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the class below which is causing the issue...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zp8s3/)

```
a.tooltip img {
   position:absolute;
   border:0;
   margin:-10px 0 0 -55px;
   float:left;
}
```

So use this to fix

```
a.tooltip img.static {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

You need to use `class="static"`(You can use any name) on your `img` tag.

I would like to suggest you to clean up your code as it's damn messy.

Comment: Thanks, that's worked a treat. Could you elaborate on 'messy'? Are you referring to the indentation? Or the MARKUP? Thanks agin.

Comment: @OamPsy No, the styles, they are affecting your image, as well the images in the tool tip and you welcome :)

Comment: Ah i see. There is a dotted line now appear under the image. What causes this?

Comment: @OamPsy That's why I told you it's messy, look here `a.tooltip {
border-bottom:1px dotted #000;`

Answer (score 2):

**Check this demo**  May be useful for you

[CSS TOOLTIP](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip)

Answer (score 1):

Set **position: relative;** in your anchor class **tooltip**
remove **top:2em;** from **a.tooltip span**

Hope this will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're using to much negative margins. i.e

```
...    
margin-left:-99em;
...
margin:-10px 0 0 -55px;
```

And if you already know the size of your icon you could  set the top and left without relative values

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RLvVw/)